# Extract content from a url to a div

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to extract the "container" div from the url     http://rid3201.org/site/club_members2.php?id=MTk3Ng==. I use following codes for that(in MVC4)

my controller

```
 public string DownloadUrlData()
    {
        using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            string htmlCode = wc.DownloadString("http://rid3201.org/site/club_members2.php?id=MTk3Ng==");
            return htmlCode;
        }
    }
```

and my html page and jquery is

```
  @section head{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax(
        {
        url: '/Member/DownloadUrlData',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (request) {

        },
        success: function (data) {
          var theHtml = $(data).find('#container>table:first').html();
          // var $theTable = $(theHtml);
           $("#rData").append(theHtml);
          // Use this HTML or jQuery object to serve your objective
       },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert(textStatus + ", " + errorThrown + ", " + xmlHttpRequest);
        },
        complete: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus) {
       }
   });


    });
</script>
 }

 <div id="rData">

 </div>
```

i want to append that table(in container div) into the div rData. i can get the whole html code(in data). but cann't extract and load into the rData div. That part is not working .

I found the the problem is jquery cannt access  in the data. how can i remove this

Comment: _"How this possible."_ - more or less the way you're doing it. Is anything happening?

Comment: What is the problem or error ?

Comment: i can get the whole html code(in data). but cann't extract container div and load into the rData div. That part is not working

Comment: Not working is not an error. Use a proper browser with a console and see what errors the browser shows.

Comment: i use firefox and chrome.

Comment: That's nice. Did you check their error console?

Comment: CodeCaster: the problem is jquery cannt access <!DOCTYPE html> in the data. how can i remove this

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML is a tedious thing to do. But I would handle it on the backend rather then in the javascript frontend. Especially so you can update the code to adapt to any changes easily on 1 location.

I would use the http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ and parse the htmlCode string you have, take out the table you require and send this back to the client so you can directly append the data rather then having to figure it out client side.